# EMR & Spark 3.0: row-level security (filtering)

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, apache-ranger

Question: *is it possible to achieve row-level filtering with EMR, Spark 3.0 & S3 without purchasing expensive enterprise solutions?*

I want to make sure I haven't missed anything. [EMR-Ranger doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-ranger-app-support.html) says integration supports Spark, but it looks totally useless, because:

1. If works through EMR Record Server 
    It should provide fine-grained access controll, but [Ranger plugins doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-ranger-plugins.html) says with EMR Spark Plugin doesn't support write operations, write to CSV & Auro, Delta and Hudi, row filtering and data masking.
2. If works through EMRFS S3 Ranger Plugin 
   Only coarse-grained (db-/table-/column- level) access control. No row-level filtering or data masking (due to storage level auth). See [Ranger plugins doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-ranger-plugins.html)

P.S. Hive isn't an option and Lake Formation doesn't support EMR 6.x (Spark 3.x).

Answer (score 2):

Question: your Q1) *..is it possible to achieve row-level filtering with EMR, Spark 3.0 & S3.. without expensive solutions..?* your Q2 2) ..Only coarse-grained (db-/table-/column- level) access control. `No row-level filtering or data`... I listed the *code snippet below to handle this below*..

> **Answer:** to *avoid* paying for something like privacera, I implemented *my own* `row-level filtering` for reports by forcing a `rowfilter` policy and passing it a [`"rowFilterPolicyItems"`](http://ranger.apache.org/apidocs/xml_ns0_rangerPolicyItemAccess.html), see both 1) `JSON` and 2) `Java` sample /options below, hopefully you should be able to extend this for your custom needs.

---

AWS DOCS sucks..:

As of Aug 2021, reads are possible, but writes (regardless of a plug-in) are not supported *[see AWS Ranger Docs here..](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/01/amazon-emr-now-supports-apache-ranger-for-fine-grained-data-access-control/)*

> ... Here are some considerations and limitations before you enable Apache Ranger integration on Amazon EMR. 1/ Row-level authorization and data masking policies are currently only supported with Apache Hive. 2/ The EMR Ranger-Spark plugin enforces fine-grained authorization when reading and writing data using the Spark API with Java, Scala, R, and Pyspark. `However, writing data using Spark SQL on Ranger-Enabled Clusters is currently not supported`; only reading data using SparkSQL is supported. ...

[image: Amazon EMR Row level filtering operations writes vs reads]

---

Update 1:
Even AWS own samples doesn't know how to tackle it as seen below, so I rolled my own, by looking at the code in Apache...

[image]

> #### **Answer**: WorkAround -- So I implemented these in `ranger` `rowfilter` and `"rowFilterPolicyItems"` on my own inside.

1. ##### **Option 1 JSON SEtup**

```
{
  "rowFilterInfo" : {
    "filterExpr" : "..."
  },
  "roles" : [ "...", "..." ],
  "groups" : [ "...", "..." ],
  "conditions" : [ {
    "type" : "...",
    "values" : [ "...", "..." ]
  }, {
    "type" : "...",
    "values" : [ "...", "..." ]
  } ],
  "delegateAdmin" : true,
  "accesses" : [ {
    "type" : "...",
    "isAllowed" : true
  }, {
    "type" : "...",
    "isAllowed" : true
  } ],
  "users" : [ "...", "..." ]
}
```

---

*For e.g.* you have to **implement** `"rowFilterPolicyItems"` you can use what I have sample below..

```
  // you would setup/pass this in your JSON file
  // Or, you can also do it Programmatically in Java
  "rowFilterPolicyItems": [
    {
      "rowFilterInfo": {
        "filterExpr": "page='ranger-aws-emr3.tykt.org'"
      },
      "accesses": [
        {
          // **** I Would tinker with this access type,
          // if you are doing it Java I will paste a sample below
          "type": "select",
          "isAllowed": true
        }
      ],
      "users": [
        "reports"
      ],
      "groups": [],
      "conditions": [],
      "delegateAdmin": false
    }
  ], ...
```

---

2. ##### **Option 2 JAva SEtup**

> In Java you can programmatically setup as below `RangerPolicy.RangerPolicyItem policyItem = new RangerPolicy.RangerPolicyItem();` these policies can be added to the row filter item. Since AWS was missing this I had to do ALL of this on my OWN. Lots of trial and error, but it paid off.

```java
 void createTyktPolicies(RangerService createdTyktRecordsPolicyService) throws Exception {
    RangerBaseService svc = serviceMgr.getRangerServiceByService(createdTyktRecordsPolicyService, this);
    if (svc != null) {
        List<String> serviceCheckUsers = getServiceCheckUsers(createdTyktRecordsPolicyService);
        // *** your policy as needed
        List<RangerPolicy.RangerPolicyItemAccess> allAccesses = svc.getAndAllowAllAccesses();
        List<RangerPolicy> defaultPolicies = svc.getDefaultRangerPolicies();
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(defaultPolicies)) {
            createDefaultPolicyUsersAndGroups(defaultPolicies);
            for (RangerPolicy defaultPolicy : defaultPolicies) {
                if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(serviceCheckUsers) && StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(defaultPolicy.getService(), createdTyktRecordsPolicyService.getName())) {

                // this is where I am creating my policy in code
                // You CAN MODIFY THE POLICY ACCORDINGLY to your needs and try
                    RangerPolicy.RangerPolicyItem policyItem = new RangerPolicy.RangerPolicyItem();
                    policyItem.setUsers(serviceCheckUsers);
                    policyItem.setAccesses(allAccesses);
                    policyItem.setDelegateAdmin(true);
                    defaultPolicy.getPolicyItems().add(policyItem);
                }
                createPolicy(defaultPolicy);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: pretty crappy indeed, but may take as well

Comment: @Transformer thank you for the great answer! Sorry for not rewarding you immediately, I gone to vacay. I'll be able to reward you with bounty in 24 hours.